# How to call a write function of contract from Dapp?

Tags: contract-invocation, dapps

I have created a smart contract in which a "stop()" function should be called once a deadline is reached. Dapp is keeping check of the deadline and as soon as the deadline is reached I need to call this function, the function itself actually sends some amount of ethers to 3 different addresses.

Here is the stop function:

```
function stop() public{
    require(now > deadline, "deadline expired");
    require(address(this).balance >= 1 ether, "contract doesnot have sufficient ethers");
   // quickSort(top, 0, top.length-1);
   for(uint i = 0; i < registeredStudents; i++)
        sort(i);
    // distribute the tokens
    for(uint i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        students[top[i]].wallet.transfer((3-i) * 100000000000000000);
        emit Transferred(students[top[i]].wallet, top[i], 3-i);
        students[top[i]].totalBalance += (3-i) * 100000000000000000;
    }
}
```

How can I call this function from the Dapp? I tried using call() but it is not working and I tried send() too but send() wants me to give from address as well, which I dont know should be what in this case.

Please suggest. It is urgent task. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to use `send`. Here is the code:

```
    const result = await contract.methods.stop()
          .send( { gas: '1500000', gasPrice: `30000000000000`, from:accounts[0]});
```

This code needs to be placed in an `async` function as it uses the `async/await` pattern!

Regarding your question with the from address. This is a state changing transaction. Therefore, it needs to be mined and costs gas!!

You need to access one of you accounts. Initialize web3 with your provider.

```
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

Now get the accounts.

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

This array now gets passed into the `send` function you see above.

**EDIT:** Adjust value of gas and gasPrice to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks, I know this way but isn't there any automatic way to do this? because in reality I want the dapp to do itself instead of asking user to confirm the transaction.

Comment: I don't know how your dapp exactly works, but it seems like you need to call this function a lot of times. There is the option that you pay for the tx cost (as the transaction SURELY costs gas).